# performselector afterdelay not working

Tags: ios, ios5, thread-safety

i am using the following method in a uiview subclass:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(timeout) withObject:nil afterDelay:20];
```

The method is called after 20 seconds as expected.
In another method i try to cancel the perform request using the following code:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timeout) object:nil];
```

i've also tried

```
[NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timeout) object:nil];
```

both messages don't bring the expected result an the timeout method is still called.
can anybody explain me what i am doing wrong and how to do it the right way ?

cheers from austria
martin

Comment: its working fine, i just tried your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two points
1. Are both `self` same object??
2. Is `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timeout) object:nil];` performed on same thread on which you called `[self performSelector:@selector(timeout) withObject:nil afterDelay:20];` ?

Check these two problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use an NSTimer stored as an instance variable in your class. When you want to cancel the perform, invalidate and destroy the timer.

In your @interface:

```
@property (readwrite, retain) NSTimer *myTimer;
```

In your @implementation:

```
self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:20 target:self selector:@selector(timeout) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then, if some condition happens and the timeout method should no longer be called:

```
[self.myTimer invalidate];
self.myTimer = nil; // this releases the retained property implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(timeout) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with 2 ways :

1. You could use this which would remove all queued

   [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
2. you can remove each one individually

   [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                            selector:@selector(timeout)
                                              object:nil];